OPA rego check for tags in AWS Resources from Terraform JSON
I am trying to write a policy where I want to enforce tags to exist on AWS resources using Open Policy Agent (OPA). I am attempting to parse the JSON output of a run of terraform plan in order to enforce policies on new resources in the root module.
So far, I have a simple filter set up that works just fine:
filter_taggable_resources = filtered {
  ...
}

The list of tags I want to validate is pretty simple:
required_tags := {"foo", "bar", "baz"}

In my validataion area, I want to:

make sure the resource has tags actually defined
make sure that the required tags are present
allow for any additional tags to be set on top of the required ones

I was hoping to set up something like this (pardon the pseudo-code, I am very new at OPA Rego):
get_missing_tags(resource) = missing_tags {
  missing_tags := required_tags
  resource_tags := resource.values.tags

  # if resource_tags is null - fail and return all tags
  resource_tags != null

  # if we got this far, run a diff and return the tags
  missing_tags = required_tags - resource_tags
}

violation[msg] {
  filtered := filter_taggable_resources
  resource := filtered[_]
  missing_tags := get_missing_tags(resource)
  count(missing_tags) != 0
  msg = sprintf("My error message: %v", [concat(", ", missing_tags)])
}

I believe I am completely missing some concepts figuring this out and cannot get it to return properly. I do NOT want it to fail fast and I want it to loop over all resources and give me errors for each and every one. I want to expand this later to check for valid values for the tags, but I want to solve the more simple problem first.
My core problem is that I am only getting an error if tags exist. If I have the following resources:
resource "aws_instance" "bla1" {
  ami           = local.some_ami
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_instance" "bla2" {
  ami           = local.some_ami
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags          = { Name = "IHaveATagButNotAll" }
}

I only get errors for aws_instance.bla2 in my output and nothing for aws_instance.bla1, even though it doesn't have any tags. How can I set this up?
My execution is:
conftest test /path/to/tfplan.json \
  --policy /path/to/policies \
  --all-namespaces \
  --fail-on-warn \
  --show-builtin-errors \
  --strict

With:

Conftest: v0.52.0
OPA: 0.64.1


I was able to solve this using multiple violation blocks, but it seems like I should be able to do this in a single block.
